# command line tool for print picture?

Tags: windows, command-line, printing

My program needs to print a curve; my solution is changing the curve into a picture, and this picture file (xxx.png) can be printed by using the default windows picture printing tool (right click the mouse on top of the file, and select print).

but I don't want user do this job manually, I need a command line tool to do this:

```
printPicture xxx.png
```

How can I do this in command line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally found out!

use windows image and fax viewer.

```
rundll32    shimgvw.dll    ImageView_PrintTo /pt   xxx.png   "printer name"
```

Comment: Careful, you can't give any options with this solution, and you can't change default options (picture will be fitted to A4).

Comment: how to print in 8mm paper ?

Comment: No clue why, but this doesn't work for me on a Windows 10 desktop. Neither does the `print` command (with a txt file). I had to resort to mspaint... which is acceptable I guess

Answer (score 14):

[This link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/87e942da-faec-48e1-b339-7ba3da7c9134) had a simpler solution:

```
mspaint /pt [image filename]
```

Comment: thank you, save my life.

this is very cool, i coding it on my python django app: 

 cmd = f'mspaint /pt {filename}'
 p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
 p.wait()

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem that mspaint allows you to set default printing settings yourself.

Answer (score 11):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is able to do this.  Here's a list of [command line options](http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/IrfanView_Command_Line_Options) for this application.

The following *should* work:

```
i_view32 xxx.png /print
```

If you want to print to a printer **other** than the default printer, specify the printer name:

```
i_view32 xxx.png /print="PrinterName"
```

Comment: You asked for a command line tool... that's what I've posted.  How you use this in your application is up to you - you're the developer!

Comment: This rocks ! irfanView keep your last printing options. When you call it to print a picture through command line, it uses last printing options. It's perfect.

Comment: Great!!! It works perfect. First we need to install inrfan_view from here http://www.irfanview.com/ and then run this command in windows **`& 'C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe' .\test_image.png /print`**

Answer (score 2):

```
rundll32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo "c:\mydir\my.bmp" "Fictional HP Printer"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rundll32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo "c:\mydir\my.bmp" "Fictional HP Printer"
```

This prints an image file (.png in my case) to a specified printer WITHOUT a dialog box popping up. Also... works without elevated command prompt privileges.

Answer (score -1):

You can call [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) from your program with `print` operation:

```
ShellExecute(NULL,"print","c:\\test.png",NULL,NULL,SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: "print" is only for TXT files