# Can I use Command Line to print photo and set print setting

Tags: command-line, printing

I am trying to print photos from my application (Unity3D's game & script language is C# ) and I think using ***.bat*** is the simplest way to do that.

Batch file content :

```
"C:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe" /p "C:\Users\Jason\Documents\UnityProjects\Test-Printing\Assets\test.png"
```

This allow the application printing photo(screenshot from Unity3D) with mspaint(Microsoft Paint)'s ***"default print setting"***.

Is there any way to set print setting through Command Line in order to print photo without ***"default print setting"***.

Comment: `Spring-Batch` is not the same as a `batch-file`.  Different languages.

Comment: From what I can tell you will not be able to control the print settings unless you use a third party tool. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301101/command-line-tool-for-print-picture

Comment: @Squashman I tested IrfanView before it allow me change and save the print settings .But it always print one more blank page(photo) so I am trying to use mspaint.

Answer (score 1):

The default printer is chosen because the last parameter in your code is omitted, so far, here are the possible parameters:

```
mspaint /pt [file name] [printer name]
```

for example:

```
"C:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe" /p "C:\Users\Jason\Documents\UnityProjects\Test-Printing\Assets\test.png" "Microsoft Print to PDF"
```

so in short, this should be helpful

```
"C:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe" /p "C:\Users\Jason\Documents\UnityProjects\Test-Printing\Assets\test.png" "INSERT_NAME_OF_YOUR_PRINTER_HERE"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain your answer so others can understand easily.