# how to print a png/jpeg/pdf to my default printer everyday at a specifc time

Tags: python, printing

i tried doing this, but it does not work with png, if you can  help out, that would be great!

```
import datetime


while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour == 8 and now.minute == 10:
        os.startfile(r'''D:\testpage.png''', "print")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to be done with python? Instead of writing a program that runs in the background and checks the time, it is better to use a built-in solution in your OS like cron.

You can find here how to run scheduled tasks on Windows: [Setting up a cron job in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows)

And how to print files from command line: [command line tool for print picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301101/command-line-tool-for-print-picture)

Comment: not necessary to be done with python, i believe cron is for linux, and task scheduler can run a program/script.. still need a way to print png with a script/program

Comment: you can write a short script in batch file or power shell and add it to scheduled tasks. Batch file just contains list of commands you can run from cmd terminal. If you need variable image to be printed you can pass it as an argument to your script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-a-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

Answer: i used the command

```
mspaint /pt [image filename]
```

using  notepad and saved it as a batch file, and used Windows Task Scheduler to run the batch file  everyday Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Can you share a full code snippet that you have used to make the answer meet the quality standard here?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).